# Can you style elements triggered with a [disabled] property in Angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this button which launches a form on my site:

```
<button (click)="create()" *ngIf="data.new" [disabled]="!dataForm.valid" color="primary" mat-raised-button>
   Go
</button>
```

When certain conditions are met, it disables all fields.

My question is, can I use css to style the form ONLY when it's affected by [disabled]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eudz answer is definitely a good way of tackling it. But in case you wan't to role a style out on a more global basis for something like an invalid input box you can also target using CSS. Angular will place classes on the form inputs for you such as `ng-invalid` `ng-valid` `ng-pristine` etc etc.

So you could target these with CSS.

**For Example**

```
input.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure, for example you want to customize an input when your form is invalid :

```
<input type="text" [class.border-danger]="!dataForm.valid">
```

or

```
<input type="text" [class.border-danger]="dataForm.invalid">
```

I passed `!dataForm.valid` because it was the condition for the button to be disabled.